# Routing & pretty URL

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am looking to create prettier URLs, and I'm having issues creating a valid route:

Let's say I have the following page http://localhost/app/account/5/edit.

This works fine with **Route::get('account/{account}', 'AccountController@edit');**

If I modify the *Account Model* and modify *getRouteKeyName* to **return 'name'**, I am able to (with the same Route from above) access the following link: http://localhost/app/account/randomName/edit

The thing is, I am interested in a slightly different route, which is: http://localhost/app/account/randomName-5/edit

If I create a route **Route::get('/accounts/{ignore}-{account}/edit', 'AccountController@edit')**, it will fail as the first argument sent to edit is string and not an instance of Account. This can easily be fixed by modifying **edit(Account $ac)** to **edit($ignored, Account $ac);**... but it feels like cheating.

Is there a way to to get the route to ignore the first {block}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, you can [customize your resolution logic](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding) for route model binding.

In this scenario, you can do something like this in App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('accountNameWithId', function ($value) {
        list($accountName, $accountId) = explode('-', $value);

        return App\Account::whereKey($accountId)
            ->where('name', $accountName)
            ->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

Then you can redefine your route like this:

```
Route::get('account/{accountNameWithId}', 'AccountController@edit');
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks.

By the way, it's explode() not implode()

Also, I removed the where('name') as I'm actually only searching by the account_id.